# how to enable scp only on public interface and ssh only in internal interface

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

Server A has a public ip and a private ip, each on another vlan and thus on another virtual interface.

How can I enable scp only on the public ip and ssh only on the private IP, for all users.

Kind regards

Hannes De Bondt

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/83856/allow-scp-but-not-actual-login-using-ssh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SCP is ssh. There is no "server" as in ftp, that listens, aside from the sshd daemon. If you enable ssh connection, you also enable scp (which is not a distinct protocl) and vice versa..

Comment: It's possible to limit a user's ssh access to only run scp. sshd can apply rules based on the local address which a user connected to. It's probably possible to force scp on connections to a particular interface.

Answer (score 0):

Actually scp transfers files over SSH protocol, so you need SSH access to the machine to be able to use scp.

If you are concerned about security a firewall is what you need - blocking access from unwanted visitors on the public interface.

Alternatively you can configure sshd to listen on the private IP only and setup an OpenVPN server to gain access to the server from a remote location.