# Replacement for scponly on Debian

Tags: ssh, debian

scponly has been [removed](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=650590) from Debian packages. I'm using scp to pull backups from a Debian 8 server and for previous Debian servers I've set the login shell to `scponly` in order to restrict the backup user. What is a good replacement shell for scponly, or what configuration can be made to sshd to provide security equivalent to scponly?

Comment: Maybe [rssh](http://www.pizzashack.org/rssh/) with `allowscp` uncommented in `/etc/rssh.conf` is a good solution?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/a/507899/120438 is not quite a duplicate, but the answer might be applicable.

Comment: Thanks @jenny-d. In addition to using `rssh` I've restricted based on hostname as described in the answer.

Comment: This is discussed at http://serverfault.com/q/83856/107832