# scp - What do the "-d" and "-t" options do?

Tags: ssh, command-line-interface, scp

I ran into [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/83856/allow-scp-but-not-actual-login-using-ssh/88864#88864?newreg=11fb91f487a44367aac43defb27c199f) post that suggests adding the following to `.ssh/authorized_keys` in order to force an `scp` command :

```
no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty,command="scp -v -r -d -t ~/CONTENT" ssh-rsa AAAAMYRSAKEY...
```

The solution works great but I couldn't find any information about the `-d` and `-t` options in the `scp` manual. After some searching I managed to find [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23637594/scp-problems-with-t-flag-stalling) that shed some light`:

> scp `-t` is normally the receiving end of an scp transfer. It's launched
>   by another scp instance which is going to send files to the receiving
>   end. The sending scp instance starts the receiver, sends the C line to
>   mark that a file is coming, then sends the data for the file.

Any idea what what effect the `-d` option has?

Also, out of curiosity, does anyone know if/where I could find an official description. I wasn't able to find anything in the source code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `-d` flag is a server flag like `-t`. In this case it means that the target should be a directory (versus a regular file) -- attempts to `scp` to a file instead of into a directory will be killed.

In the current OpenSSH source code, `-d` is caught [here](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/606077ee1e77af5908431d003fb28461ef7be092/scp.c#L495), [sets](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/606077ee1e77af5908431d003fb28461ef7be092/scp.c#L496) the `targetshouldbedirectory` flag and then is checked [here](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/606077ee1e77af5908431d003fb28461ef7be092/scp.c#L567). If `verifydir()` is false, the (host-side) process [is killed](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/606077ee1e77af5908431d003fb28461ef7be092/scp.c#L1644).

n.b. I could not find an official description but did find it in the source I've linked.

Comment: is this a openssh flag only? This has no mention in the man pages.

Comment: That's the premise of the question: these are undocumented flags. I didn't look at any other SSH implementation.